# Autoplay embedded Youtube playlist

Tags: youtube, playlist, autoplay

I followed the instructions on [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)
and the embedded Youtube playlist which should Autoplay is:

```
<iframe width="535" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PL8kx4WFqlOK90fxZpao5k2WUEmSPchGhR&autoplay=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

It does loop when it reaches the last clip, but it won't play automatically on page load. Is there a fix for this, please? Thanks.

PS. I know this question has been asked before, but I could not find a working solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLElJF-XLNL2Brb_dTiVNSe9qld1eR_Jft&autoplay=1&loop=1
```

#### Google Chrome:

Since Google Chrome removed *non-muted* autoplay functionality in version 66, you have to add the parameter "mute=1" in that browser.
Or change autoplay-policy in the chrome settings:
[How to allow video autoplay in a Google Chrome kiosk app in version 66 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921453/how-to-allow-video-autoplay-in-a-google-chrome-kiosk-app-in-version-66-or-later/50222347#50222347)

Comment: not working for me inside CustomTab (Chrome), even with `mute=1`