# Chrome latest version not autostart Youtube

Tags: google-chrome, youtube-api, google-chrome-os

The Google Chrome latest version 66.0.3359.139 (April 26, 2018) does not allow to autostart not muted Youtube Videos, now like in Android or iOS. 
I'm not sure at all if the problem is the new Google Chrome version os a new Youtube API version or policy, but I can't find any changes made on it. 
I saw the problem in an application running in Mac and in ChromeOS (Chromebit) with the iframe embed player with javascript API enabled.

Has somebody information? Can it be an issue, or a new security or performance policy?

---

EDIT:

### It does not happen always but almost.

---

EDIT 2:
Certainly I got this error trying tu put in mute and unmute with a setTimeout of 4000 ms and I've got the error:
"Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before"

### But why now?

Thanks!

Comment: To check on the new policy changes, you can refer in the documentation specifically on the [Autoplay Policy Changes(https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). This changes was also mentioned in [this blog](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/google-chrome-66-to-start-blocking-auto-play-video/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question asking for the same I am is better explained:

[How to allow video autoplay in a Google Chrome kiosk app in version 66 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921453/how-to-allow-video-autoplay-in-a-google-chrome-kiosk-app-in-version-66-or-later)

EDIT:
Is new policy from chrome 66 as said in the link pasted in the comment
Thank you

EDIT II:
The answer in the threat mentioned works:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222347/5154908

Answer (score 2):

[Muted autoplay is always allowed.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#iframe)

So we can append `mute=1` to the video link.

for eg: https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?playlist=VIDEO_ID&autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&rel=0

Hope this will help for someone looking for autoplay. This example will autoplay the video continuously and hide relative video pop up box.

Comment: Of course, but I need the videos with sound. Thanks